# Flash Media Server NetConnection problem with Client Object

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-media-server, netconnection

i am connecting successfully to an fms with the following command:

```
netConnection = new NetConnection();
netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
netConnection.client = new Object();
netConnection.connect( AppConfig.FMS_ADDRESS );
```

now in the event handler:

```
if ( event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success" ) {
    trace( netConnection.client.id );
    remoteSlices = SharedObject.getRemote( "slices", netConnection.uri, true );
    remoteSlices.addEventListener( SyncEvent.SYNC, onRemoteSync );
    remoteSlices.connect( netConnection );
}
```

my problem is, that the netConnection.client.id is undefined, while at the same time on the server i can trace the client id without a problem.

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `netConnection.client` is an empty object, just as you defined it to be, with the following line:

```
netConnection.client = new Object();
```

To retrieve the id of the client you'll have to send it from the server to the client. [I'm sure you know how to do that](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000164.html) :).

Comment: thanks kevin! i thought it would get set automatically. sending it should indeed be no problem.